# Configuring Outlook Social Connector for SharePoint via Group Policy

Tags: group-policy

Its possible to configure whether the [Social functionality of Outlook is enabled or disabled via Group Policy](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2020103), however, it would be nice to actually setup the SharePoint social connector for Outlook in an administrative way so that we can bring our users closer to their my site profiles and begin using them as a hub of information sharing to start pulling them away from email.

Does anyone know a way of achieving this?